# eclipse xml problems

Tags: eclipse

Hi guys I'm using Eclipse in order to develop an android Application.When I'm building its layout when I try to drag an drop a second textField into the screen i get this error{

### Error

```
Sun Oct 21 20:32:14 EEST 2012
row2.xml: java.util.LinkedHashMap.eldest()Ljava/util/Map$Entry;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.LinkedHashMap.eldest()Ljava/util/Map$Entry;
    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:206)
    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:306) {......}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your TextView

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Hope helped..!